# android -How to push notification without using GSM

Tags: android

I can't use GSM in my country because google is not allowing .I need to make an application to send message to my users really time . I may want to send about 10 messages per day to my users . I've webserver .

Is there another feature or other ways to send push notification to my users ?

Comment: then lists all the possible options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27648326/send-notification-although-user-is-logged-out

Answer (score 1):

[Parse.com](https://parse.com/). You need to register users to this site/cloud. Easy to implement with Push Notification and other features as well.